# ¿como puedo hacer para que no me salgan numeros en mi script al momento de recuperar informacion? MVC C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

el problema es el siguiente: estoy utulizando mvc en visual estudio, el problema es cuando deseo recuperar la informacion dentro de un script el cual lo realizo con un @foreach, en donde la informacion que envio tiene comillas, las cuales despues se cambian con numero, lo cual hace erroneo el funcionamiento del mismo, en todo caso, ¿que puedo hacer para que no salgan los numeros?

**[image: como mando la informacion]
[image: esto es lo que necesito mandar]
[image: Aqui es como recupero la lista]
[image: y este es el resultado, pero quiero que aparezca sin los numeros]

Comment: Hola @Elisandro, bienvenido al sitio , sería mucho mejor que el código de su pregunta donde está presentando problemas lo añada en formato texto y no en imágenes para mejorar la legibilidad y el entendimiento y así se pueda brindar una mejor respuesta a su pregunta.

Comment: Explorando llegué a esta pregunta pero no veo nada de código por la restricción de mi red para ver imágenes de imgur. A pesar de ya estar resuelta, en futuras preguntas [**NO** pongas imágenes en lugar de código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por defecto ASP.NET MVC realiza un `HtmlEncode` del contenido que envías en la vista. Para evitar que realice esta codificación deberías utilizar el método `Raw` del `HtmlHelper`:

```
@Html.Raw(item)
```